# How to select one column with panda dataframe on a wiki table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been practicing web scraping and this time I'm trying to get only the first column of data (only the stock symbols) all the way down but it keeps pulling all the data from the table?
Not sure what I'm doing wrong any assistance would be appreciated thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

tables= pd.read_html(url, attrs={'id': 'constituents'})
df = df.iloc[1:]
print (df)
#df.to_csv('Stock_List.txt', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Use `df = df.iloc[:, 0]` The first value is row numbers the second is column numbers. Integer indexes start at 0 in pandas.

Comment: first you need `df = tables[0]` and later `df = df['Symbol']`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get single table from all tables.

And next you can get column `Symbols`

```
df = tables[0]

df = df['Symbol']
```

---

Full working code

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"

tables = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'id': 'constituents'})

df = tables[0]

print(df['Symbol'])
```

---

If you want also links assigned to symbols then you will have to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` because `read_html` can't give it.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

r = requests.get(url)
    
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    
symbols = []
    
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:  # [1:] to skip header
    items = row.find_all('td')
    symbol = items[0].text.strip()
    link = items[0].find('a')['href']
    symbols.append([symbol, link])
    print(f"{symbol:5} | {link}")

#print(symbols)
```

Result:

```
MMM   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:MMM
ABT   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ABT
ABBV  | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ABBV
ABMD  | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abmd
ACN   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ACN
ATVI  | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/atvi
ADBE  | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/adbe
AMD   | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amd
AAP   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAP
AES   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AES
AFL   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AFL
A     | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:A
APD   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:APD
AKAM  | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/akam
ALK   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ALK
ALB   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ALB
ARE   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ARE
ALGN  | http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/algn
ALLE  | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ALLE
LNT   | https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:LNT

# ... etc ...
```

It based on my code from answer for: [Running for-loop and skipping stocks with 'KeyError' : Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003872/running-for-loop-and-skipping-stocks-with-keyerror-date)

The same code is also on `GitHub` in my repo:

`python-examples`/`__scraping__`/[wikipedia.org - SP500 - requests, BS](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/__scraping__/wikipedia.org%20-%20SP500%20-%20requests%2C%20BS/main.py)